# NullPointerException while retrieving Image from SQLite Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to insert an Image into SQLite Database and retrieve it. I think the data is inserted successfully,but the program stops while retrieving it. Can you please help me?. Logcat shows 
java.lang.NullPointerException at com.example.mypassword.Login$1.onClick(Login.java:51)

I have attached the code to insert and retrieve the Image. This is my SQLiteOpenHelper class.

```
public class SQL extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public static final String DB_NAME="New.db";
public static final String TABLE_NAME="Sample";
public static final int DB_VERSION=1;

public static final String NAME="Name";
public static final String NO="No";
public static final String IMG="Img";
public static final String PIXELX="PosX";
public static final String PIXELY="PosY";

Cursor cur;
byte[] blob;
String name;
String no;
int pixelx,pixely;
Bitmap bmp;

Context ctxt;
//private DatabaseHelper mDbHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase mDb;

public SQL(Context context)
{
    super(context,DB_NAME,null,1);
}
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
{
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_NAME+"("+NAME +" TEXT NOT NULL "+","+ NO +" TEXT PRIMARY KEY ,"+IMG +" BLOB,"+PIXELX +" INTEGER, "+ PIXELY +" INTEGER);");
}
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db,int old,int newversion)
{
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS"+TABLE_NAME+";");
    onCreate(db);
}
public void drop(SQLiteDatabase db)
{
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME+" ;");
}
public void open(SQLiteDatabase db)
{
    db=this.getWritableDatabase();
}
public void close(SQLiteDatabase db)
{
    db.close();
}

public void insert(SQLiteDatabase db,String name,String no,Bitmap ImgData,int pixelx,int pixely)
{
    //db=this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues con=new ContentValues();
    con.put(NAME, name);
    con.put(NO, no);
    con.put(IMG, Utility.getBytes(ImgData));
    con.put(PIXELX, pixelx);
    con.put(PIXELY, pixely);
    db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, con);
}


@SuppressLint("NewApi") public User  retrieve(SQLiteDatabase db)
{
    cur=db.query(true,TABLE_NAME, new String[]{NAME,NO,IMG,PIXELX,PIXELY},null, null,null, null,null, null,null);
    //cur=db.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[]{IMG},null, null,null, null, null);

    if(cur.moveToFirst())
    {
        name=cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(NAME));
        no=cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(NO));
         blob=cur.getBlob(cur.getColumnIndex(IMG));
         pixelx=cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex(PIXELX));
         pixely=cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex(PIXELY));
        cur.close();
        return new User(name,no,Utility.getPhoto(blob),pixelx,pixely);
    }
        cur.close();
        return null;
}

public ArrayList<Cursor> getData(String Query){
    //get writable database
    SQLiteDatabase sqlDB = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String[] columns = new String[] { "mesage" };
    //an array list of cursor to save two cursors one has results from the query 
    //other cursor stores error message if any errors are triggered
    ArrayList<Cursor> alc = new ArrayList<Cursor>(2);
    MatrixCursor Cursor2= new MatrixCursor(columns);
    alc.add(null);
    alc.add(null);


    try{
        String maxQuery = Query ;
        //execute the query results will be save in Cursor c
        Cursor c = sqlDB.rawQuery(maxQuery, null);


        //add value to cursor2
        Cursor2.addRow(new Object[] { "Success" });

        alc.set(1,Cursor2);
        if (null != c && c.getCount() > 0) {


            alc.set(0,c);
            c.moveToFirst();

            return alc ;
        }
        return alc;
    } catch(SQLException sqlEx){
        Log.d("printing exception", sqlEx.getMessage());
        //if any exceptions are triggered save the error message to cursor an return the arraylist
        Cursor2.addRow(new Object[] { ""+sqlEx.getMessage() });
        alc.set(1,Cursor2);
        return alc;
    } catch(Exception ex){

        Log.d("printing exception", ex.getMessage());

        //if any exceptions are triggered save the error message to cursor an return the arraylist
        Cursor2.addRow(new Object[] { ""+ex.getMessage() });
        alc.set(1,Cursor2);
        return alc;
    }


}
```

}

This is my Code to insert data

```
 public class Register extends Activity {
 ImageView img;
 String picpath;
 Bitmap bmp;
 Canvas cnvs;
 Random r;
 int x,y,height,width;
 ByteArrayOutputStream blob;
 SQL sql;
 Paint paint;
 String name,no;
 Uri data;
 SQLiteDatabase db;
 String[] filePath={MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};;
 Cursor cur;
 TextView txt;
 int colIndex;
 byte[] imgData;

public Register()
{

}

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.register);



    img=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    sql=new SQL(this);
    db=sql.getWritableDatabase();
    sql.drop(db);
    sql.onCreate(db);
    r=new Random();
    paint=new Paint();
    x=r.nextInt(100);
    blob=new ByteArrayOutputStream();


    Intent i=getIntent();
    name=i.getStringExtra("name");
    no=i.getStringExtra("no");
    //Open Button
    Button open=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
    open.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent gal_open=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(gal_open,1);

        }
    });
    txt=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    Button shuffle=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    shuffle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            bmp=Bitmap.createBitmap(img.getHeight(),img.getWidth(),Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
            cnvs=new Canvas(bmp);

            height=img.getMeasuredHeight();
            width=img.getMeasuredWidth();
            x=r.nextInt(height);
            y=r.nextInt(width);
            paint.setColor(Color.RED);


            txt.setText(x+","+y);
            cnvs.drawBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picpath), 0, 0, null);
            cnvs.drawRect(x, y,x+20,y+20 , paint);
            img.setImageBitmap(bmp);

        }
    });
    Button ok= (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    txt=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            txt.setText(x+"'"+y);
            sql.insert(db,"Vignesh","9578323986",bmp,x,y);  

        }
    });
}
public void onDraw()
{

}
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode,int resultCode,Intent intentData)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intentData);
    if(requestCode==1 && resultCode==RESULT_OK && intentData!=null)
    {

        bmp=Bitmap.createBitmap(img.getHeight(),img.getWidth(),Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
        cnvs=new Canvas(bmp);
        //img.setImageBitmap(bmp);

        height=img.getMeasuredHeight();
        width=img.getMeasuredWidth();
        x=r.nextInt(height);
        y=r.nextInt(width);
        paint.setColor(Color.RED);

        data=intentData.getData();

        cur=getContentResolver().query(data,filePath,null,null,null );
        cur.moveToFirst();

        colIndex=cur.getColumnIndex(filePath[0]);
        picpath=cur.getString(colIndex);
        cur.close();

        txt=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        txt.setText(x+","+y);
        cnvs.drawBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picpath), 0, 0, null);
        cnvs.drawRect(x, y,x+20,y+20 , paint);
        img.setImageBitmap(bmp);

    }   
}
```

}

This is my Utility class code

```
public class Utility {
    public static byte[] getBytes(Bitmap bitmap) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
        return stream.toByteArray();
    }

    // convert from byte array to bitmap
    public static Bitmap getPhoto(byte[] image) {
        return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image, 0, image.length);
    }

}
```

This is my User class code

```
public class User {
    String name,no;
    int pixelx,pixely;
    public Bitmap bmp;

    public User(String n,String num,Bitmap img,int pixel1,int pixel2)
    {
        name=n;
        no=num;
        bmp=img;
        pixelx=pixel1;
        pixely=pixel2;

    }

    public Bitmap retBmp()
    {
     return bmp;

    }

    public String Name()
    {
    return name;
    }

    public String No()
    {
        return no;
    }

    public int PixelX()
    {
        return pixelx;
    }
    public int PixelY()
    {
        return pixely;
    }
}
```

Here is the onClick where I get NullPointerException

```
public class Login extends Activity {
SQL sql;
User user;
String name;
TextView no;
ImageView img;
int imgx,imgy;
View touchlistener;
SQLiteDatabase db;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login);
    sql=new SQL(this);
    sql.open(db);
    img=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    // no=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    //name=no.getText().toString();

    **Button getimg=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    getimg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {
                user =sql.retrieve(db);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }   
            img.setImageBitmap(user.retBmp());
        }
    });**


        }

}
```

Comment: You can't just "think" that it was inserted correctly, you need to check and make sure it has.

Comment: I used AndroidDatabaseManager to check. When I try to retrieve data after inserting, it says cannot retrieve BLOB. Is there any way to check whether the data has been inserted?.Please say me

Comment: `com.example.mypassword.Login$1.onClick(Login.java:51)`. You have many onClicks. Please indicate in the code the offending line. And tell which is the null pointer.

Comment: Sorry but where is the code to retrieve the image?

Comment: Sorry, I have attached it now

Comment: `Here is the onClick where I get NullPointerException`. As asked before: Indicate exactly which line causes the exception. And post more of the logcat lines. Please remove the **'s from your post. Use normal comments instead.

Comment: Your code is wrong as you try to assign `user`. But even if that fails and catches you are using user. But if it catches user in `img.setImageBitmap(user.retBmp());` will be null and hence a NullPointerException. Put that statement in the try block too. The error tells nothing about the image stored correctly or retrieved wrong.